# how to set drop-down-list offset in ComboBox to be like the old-school style (win store app)

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-8, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml

I want the combobox's drop-down-list to be opened right from the offset of the combobox's contentPresenter (you know... the part that shows the selected item). But hat actually happens is that the dropdown-list's offset is above the contentPresenter till the page's ceiling.

As well I want the width of the drop down list to be according the largest item - permanently, and not to be changed dynamically as it now (now, it resized according to the items that are in view).

[image]

I tried to set the comboBox's MaxDropDownHeight property to 0 or 300, but nothing has changed.

Here is the templateControl (the image has nothing to do with this snippet):

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox" >
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,0" />
        <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="LeftToRight" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxForegroundThemeBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Disabled" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <CarouselPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="32" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <!--
                                        <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Highlight">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    -->
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <!--
                                        <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxPressedBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownGlyph">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    -->
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <!--
                                        <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownGlyph">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    -->
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <!--
                                        <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Highlight"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxFocusedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    -->
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="FocusedPressed">
                                    <!--
                                        <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="Highlight">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxPressedHighlightThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    -->
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="FocusedDropDown">
                                    <!--
                                        <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PopupBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    -->
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DropDownStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Opened">
                                    <!--
                                        <Storyboard>
                                        <SplitOpenThemeAnimation ClosedTargetName="ContentPresenter" ContentTranslationOffset="0" ContentTargetName="ScrollViewer" ClosedLength="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownClosedHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" OffsetFromCenter="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" OpenedTargetName="PopupBorder" OpenedLength="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOpenedHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    -->
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Closed">
                                    <!--
                                        <Storyboard>
                                        <SplitCloseThemeAnimation ClosedTargetName="ContentPresenter" ContentTranslationOffset="40" ContentTranslationDirection="{Binding TemplateSettings.SelectedItemDirection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" ContentTargetName="ScrollViewer" ClosedLength="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownClosedHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" OffsetFromCenter="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" OpenedTargetName="PopupBorder" OpenedLength="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOpenedHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    -->
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="Background"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                CornerRadius="2" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="PressedBackground"
                                   Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                   Fill="{StaticResource ComboBoxPressedHighlightThemeBrush}"
                                   Opacity="0" />
                        <Border x:Name="HighlightBackground"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                Background="{StaticResource ComboBoxFocusedBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                BorderBrush="{StaticResource ComboBoxFocusedBorderThemeBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Opacity="0" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Highlight"
                                   Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                   Fill="{StaticResource ComboBoxSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                   Opacity="0" />
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="DropDownGlyph"
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                   Margin="0,0,6,4"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   FontFamily="{StaticResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                                   FontSize="{StaticResource ComboBoxArrowThemeFontSize}"
                                   FontWeight="Bold"
                                   Foreground="Red"
                                   IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                   Text="" />
                        <Popup x:Name="Popup">
                            <Border x:Name="PopupBorder"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    Background="{StaticResource ComboBoxPopupBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource ComboBoxPopupBorderThemeBrush}"
                                    BorderThickness="{StaticResource ComboBoxPopupBorderThemeThickness}">
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer"
                                              BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}"
                                              Foreground="{StaticResource ComboBoxPopupForegroundThemeBrush}"
                                              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                              HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                                              IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}"
                                              IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}"
                                              IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}"
                                              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                              VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                                              VerticalSnapPointsAlignment="Near"
                                              VerticalSnapPointsType="OptionalSingle"
                                              ZoomMode="Disabled">
                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Border>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To size the ComboBox's faceplate to the largest item, set an explicit value for ComboBox.Width (or ComboBox.MinWidth to set a minimum but allow it to grow for larger items).  This works if you know the length of the longest item ahead of time.

ComboBox's CarouselPanel inherits from VirtualizingPanel, so since the items can be virtualized it's difficult to determine how long the longest one will be.  Setting explicit Width is probably the best way here if it works for you.

As for the ComboBox Popup's placement, the positioning logic is implementation detail that is not exposed through API as far as I know.  The ComboBox design follows Win8 design guidelines for ComboBox, which are considerate of touch, mouse, and keyboard users.  Users have expectations about how ComboBox will open, so it's best to follow guidelines here if possible.  If you do need to achive the custom behavior described above, you may be able to hack the ComboBox control to do it or create a custom solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and change the items panel of the combobox from carouselpanel to stackpanel in the style. That way the virtualization problem and combobox opening on both sides problems might be solved.

(cant check it myself right now)